# How can I set the size of an Ace activation Queue?

Tags: c++, ace

That is, how can i limit the number of tokens/elements the Queue can hold?

Example:

I have a low level driver that can only process one request at a time.

I am using the Ace activation Queue to limit the request (there could be up to 10 pending), but only one is allowed to go on the bus. The rest have to wait until the first request ends.

Thanks for helping me out.

Doron.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
an_activation_queue.queue()->high_water_mark(new_size);
```

?